# How can I constrain workspace-switching animations to their respective monitors?

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, compiz, workspaces, ccsm

Is it possible to ensure that the animation for windows while switching between workspaces stays on the window's monitor?

For example, if there is a window on the right monitor (indicated by `W` below) and one switches from Workspace `2` to Workspace `1`, the window will "fly" across the left monitor during the transition when I would like its animation to stay on the right monitor.

```
|  1           2  |
[ ] [W]  |  [ ] [ ]
```

I assumed this would be a setting in `ccsm` under either `Put` or `Desktop  Wall`, but it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It is impossible , 90% sure. The reason is that in dual monitor set up desktop spans accross two screens making it one giant desktop. So animation swaps through whole desktop, that means through the span of both monitors.

Comment: @Serg I've had it working on previous installations running 14.04. I can't seem to find a way on 16.04, though, and I can't seem to recall how I did it before.

Comment: It would happen if you aligned the screens non- overlapping vertically, but I am pretty sure you wouldn't like the functional effect.

Answer (score 0):

In `ccsm`'s `Desktop Wall`>`Viewport Switching`, set Multimonitor behavior to `Switch separately`.

Comment: That option doesn't work.